# JDO - List of Strings not being retrieved from database

Tags: java, persistence, jdo

On my `User` class I have a field that is a list of strings:

```
@Persistent
private List<String> openIds;
```

When I create a new user I do this:

```
User user = new User();
user.openIds.add(openid);
pm.makePersistent(user);
```

When I break after that last line and look, the `openIds` contains the openid I put in there.
But, when I later call `User user = pm.getObjectById(User.class, id);` with the correct id, the openIds field is an empty list.

Anyone know what could cause that?

EDIT: BTW I'm running on the Google App Engine

UPDATE: Looking at the datastore viewer, I can see the openid was correctly stored in the database. So its just not getting it out correctly...

UPDATE 2: Its working fine now.  I'm pretty sure I didn't change anything.  I think what must have happened is that there was an old version of the user object being pulled from the database.  A user object that was put in before I had the code that saves the openid.  Once I wiped the database things worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Not putting that field in the fetch plan ? 
Accessing persistent fields directly, rather than going via setters ?

Comment: Do I need to add it to the default fetch plan even though its just a list of strings?

Comment: You mean "just a list of Strings" that isn't by default in the DFG ?

Comment: Interested in how this pans out, as I'm having the same problem. I can't modify the list in the datastore as it's null. I've tried setting the fetchSize to 3, but no use. 

It'd be nice if someone had the time to do a comprehensive example..

Comment: Setting a fetchSize to 3 is of no use since it is for something else. I said put the field in the fetch plan, which it isn't by default